# Need help in making BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle work with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, cas

I have successfully implemented the FOSUserbundle as stated on the the [github site](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md). However I also need to have my site work with BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle.

The use case is that a user can register on the site however if they have SSO, that they can still sign on (and create the user locally inadvertently). I have also installed the BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle bundle according to the [github site](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/install.md)

WHat I am trying to do is show user a login form and take those credentials and run them against the local database and if they do not match, then check the SSO server. In case the SSO server is OK with the credentials, I then create the user locally.

My security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"


        my_firewall:
            pattern: ^/admin/.*$
            trusted_sso:
                manager: admin_sso
                login_action: BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:login
                logout_action: BeSimpleSsoAuthBundle:TrustedSso:logout
                create_users: true
                created_users_roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]    



    access_control:
        - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }

        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
    trusted_hosts:   ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MainReferralCaptureBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }


fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Main\ReferralCaptureBundle\Entity\User


#be_simple_sso_auth: ~


be_simple_sso_auth:
    admin_sso:
        protocol:
            id: cas
            version: 2
        server:
            id: cas
            login_url: http://cas.server.tld/login
            logout_url: http://cas.server.tld/logout
            validation_url: http://cas.server.tld/serviceValidate
```

Can someone help me with what I am trying to do?

Many many thanks in advance

Comment: Any news about this topic ???